# Creating a very basic relational RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So let's say the problem is easy:

A books application where:

```
Books
--------------
Author ID, Title, Publisher, ISBN


Authors
--------------
Author ID, Last_Name, First_Name
```

I use generate model to create these objects. 
Further, I edit the app/models/books and app/models/authors files to add associations.

Would I only have to add one association to each file? has_one :authors in books and has_many :books in authors.

Also, where exactly are fixture files? To fill in with test data? They are not showing up in test/fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you did something like the following:

```
> rails g model books author_id:integer title:string publisher:string isbn:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20111203052638_create_books.rb
  create    app/models/books.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/books_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/books.yml
> rails g model author last_name:string first_name:string
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20111203052732_create_authors.rb
  create    app/models/author.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/author_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/authors.yml
```

Fixtures should be generated along with the model in test/fixtures.

Your models should look something like this:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end

class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Comment: In the `rails g model` command, you can do `author:references` instead, and it will create a field call author_id for you, and it will also add `belongs_to :author` to the model automatically.